# Parse images from RSS when img is placed in content:encoded

Tags: android, rss, jsoup, domparser

I'm trying to parse images from RSS doing this

```
Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");

_item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
```

it is working here

working (img is in description):

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/nexus2cee_linkedin-material.png" class=" no-style"&gt;&lt;img class="alignnone size-hero-size wp-image-345522" src="http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/nexus2cee_linkedin-material-728x485.png"
```

But not here (img is in content:encoded):

```
<img class=" size-large wp-image-2207218 aligncenter" src="http://st.ilfattoquotidiano.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/14618338_small-630x404.jpg"
```

======================================================================

## **EDIT: Just found a solution. I'll leave it here for who is interested (very happy :) )**

https://github.com/enricocid/iven-feed-reader/commit/e2f8a487d0fd9dff3ca96024ddf9715e2887a916

Comment: Can you better explain what is the problem in the second case? I see that in the first example there are html entities like `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Are them ok or is it writing mistake?

Comment: this is the source code of the feeds, the first is android police and the 2nd is "il fatto quotidiano" ... from the first i can get the images, using the code i posted above, from the 2nd not and I don't why... Yesterday I've tried to see the output of getdescription ... the one for android police contains the articles images , the 2nd one not... it seems like in the 2nd one the images are in content:encoded and not in description and I don't know how to parse images from content:encoded  :/

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what is the error you get? Is `imgEle` null?

Comment: exactly, imgEle returns null :)

Comment: It would be good if you can add both the sources of the rss.

Comment: this is the source code of the app:   https://github.com/enricocid/iven-feed-reader android police feed: http://pastebin.com/Dxm6pVF8   and il fatto quotidiano: http://pastebin.com/ju6Pa37d

Answer (score 0):

You can store images/images url from RSS into a List then load image from web using Picasso .
Like this :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(data.getImage()).into(imageView);
```

Comment: I know, and I'm already doing this using glide, so this is not the problem

the problem is that the above code I posted does not work with some RSS ... read the op post better